# Axis of Symmetry

Tags: geometry, three-dimensional

**Give an example of a 3D object with *exactly* $2$ axes of symmetries?**

Definition of Axis of Symmetry:

Let $l$ be a straight line. If every point $P$ on object $O$ has a corresponding point $P'$ on $O$ such that $l$ is perpendicular to segment $PP'$ and $l$ bisects segment $PP'$, then the line $l$ is called an Axis of Symmetry of object $O$.

i.e.

> Every point on the object has a mirror image (w.r.t. the line/axis of symmetry) lying on the object itself

> If we rotate the object around the axis by $180^{\circ}$, then we get the same object.

Comment: @2012rcampion: either way, the number of answers is far greater than acceptable on this site, I believe... Good catch anyway about the difference between the definitions.

Comment: @2012rcampion: well, you are right about that. If it is rotational, then only the sphere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure such an object

> does not exist

Indeed, if an object has exactly two axes of symmetry then rotating on one of the two must map the other onto itself. Therefore they must be

> perpendicular.

But then the line perpendicular to both

> is also an axis of symmetry. One easy way to verify this is to align Cartesian coordinates with the three axes. The three rotations are then keeping one of the three coordinates fixed and flipping the signs of the other two. From this it is obvious that the product of any two is the third one.

Comment: Yes, you are right in every way :)

Answer (score -3):

A cube. A sphere. A right cylinder. A torus.

I can find other basic objects too, if needed. A right parallelepiped. A rotational ellipsoid. A rotational hyperboloid.

Some of them have not only several axis of symmetry, but entire planes of symmetry. Also symmetry around a point.

Comment: @thisIs4d: I am curious what you actually had in mind to puzzle us with :)

Comment: . . . *exactly* two axes of symmetry . . .  would be my interpretation of the question.

Comment: 1) Not my question. 2) More than two is not two. Unless the question is clearly stated, this should be the interpretation. 3) The downvote (not mine) is probably because this answer is plainly incorrect, though guessing others' motivation is not my strong point.

Comment: @virolino Since a sphere has infinite number of axes of symmetries, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @DanielMathias: word-plays are often used when presenting puzzles. So in some cases, "two" can mean "at least two". On (e.g.) Mathematics.SE I would not have made such an assumption, that would have been the wrong context. Tnx for your comment, though.

Comment: @thisIs4d: now, with the restriction of "exactly 2", the problem seems to become a "tad" more difficult. I still did not find one such object. I will keep it mind as "homework".